# Phonegap:Childbrowser not working

Tags: ios, cordova

I am working with ios phonegap application. I created a new project with phonegap2.4.0.
It was success.But my issue is childbrowser is not coming and shows following error in console:

OPENING URL:INVALID

I have done all the steps needed to include a childbrowser in the project and it is working fine in an old phonegap project.

How can i fix the problem??

```
function onBodyLoad() {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady,false);
}
function onDeviceReady() {
    cb = ChildBrowser.install();
}
function helo() {
    alert("hiiii");
    cordova.exec(null,null,"ChildBrowser","showWebPage",['google.com']);
}
```

Comment: @VickyGonsalves this is my code for calling childbrowser:   function onBodyLoad()
            {      
                document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
            }
            function onDeviceReady()
            {
                    cb =  ChildBrowser.install();
                    
                           }
        function helo()
        {
            alert("hiiii");
            cordova.exec(null,null,"ChildBrowser","showWebPage",['https://www.google.com']);
            
             
        }

Comment: R u missing http://   ?

Comment: @VickyGonsalves Iam sorry that was an editing mistake here.Actually that was nothe pblm

Comment: Phonegap 2.4 apps won't be accepted by apple as it uses udid, update to 2.5 or greater. Why do you want childbrowser? You can use inAppBrowser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function onDeviceReady() {

    if(window.plugins.childBrowser == null)
    {
        ChildBrowser.install();
    }
}

Or You can use InAppBrowser instead of childbrwoser.
For close browser use ref.close();
var ref = window.open("google.com", 'random_string', 'location=no');
ref.addEventListener('loadstart', function(event) {
        console.log(event.type + ' - ' + event.url);
} );
ref.addEventListener('loadstop', function(event) {
        console.log(event.type + ' - ' + event.url);

} );
ref.addEventListener('exit', function(event) {
                     //alert(event.type);
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function onBodyLoad() 
{ 
   document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady,false); 
} 
function onDeviceReady() 
{ 
   cb = ChildBrowser.install(); 
} 
function helo() 
{ 
    alert("hiiii"); 
    cordova.exec(null,null,"ChildBrowser","showWebPage",['http://google.com']); 
}
```